# Looping over variables to find distinct values by group in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to loop over several variables in a long-format dataframe in order to figure out the number of distinct values per variable grouped by ID.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
diagnosis <- c(890, 890, 890, 451, 659, 760, 760)
df <- data.frame(ID, diagnosis)
```

I can get it to work with just one variable:

```
d <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(distinct = n_distinct(diagnosis))

table(d$distinct)
```

but when I use lapply or a for loop to do multiple variables, it tells me that everyone only has one distinct value.

Any help would be very much appreciated, as I've spent hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: Where are the other variables in posted example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all` to include all other columns other than the grouping column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(distinct = n_distinct(.)))
```

For selected columns, use `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(colsofInterest), funs(distinct = n_distinct(.)))
```

The above creates new columns in the original dataset.  If we want to get a summarised output, use `summarise_all` or `summarise_at`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I wrap it with `funs` to create new columns with suffix `distinct`.  otherwise `mutate_all(n_distinct)` is enough but it will replace the orriginal columns with number of distinct elements by group\